# Bringing Specific Date Record in MS access using C#

Tags: c#, date, ms-access, record

I want to bring a records of commission on specific date. Here is my code;

```
globalxx = 0;
        string month1 = dateTimePicker2.Value.Month.ToString();
        string day1 = dateTimePicker2.Value.Day.ToString();
        string year1 = dateTimePicker2.Value.Year.ToString();
        string s2 = "#" + month1 + "/" + day1 + "/" + year1 + "#";
        DataTable results = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(xi))
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from COMMISSION where DateCommission='" + s2 + "'", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
       {
           new OleDbParameter("@DateCommission", s2)
       });

            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(results);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = results;
```

But the problem is it gives error at

```
adapter.Fill(results);
```

saying: "OleDB Excpetion has been handeled Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

I Need help.

My MS Access Schema is:
DateCommission: Date Time
DriverName: TEXT
DriveVehicleNumber: TEXT
CommissionedPrice: NUMBER

I am not got at parameter.

Here is the front end of c#;
[Front End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAT0d.jpg)

Comment: For More info, I want to tell that i also tried DateBetween in query, no help.

Comment: you must change the sql string: `select * from COMMISSION where DateCommission=@DateCommission`

Comment: it didn't help. :(

Comment: specify the parameter type       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCommission", new DateTime(int.Parse(year1) int.Parse(month1), int.Parse(day1)));

Comment: ok i try and tell as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Handle your date as that, and then concatenate a formatted string expression in the SQL:

```
string textDate = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
string s2 = "#" + textDate + "#";
```

and then:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from COMMISSION where DateCommission = " + s2 + "", conn);
```

Or (preferred) use a *parameter* of data type *DateTime* which you pass *Value* of the datepicker directly.

Comment: Thank You So Much :) . I have problems at
    string s2= "#"+textDate+"#";
i made mistake while taking date.

Comment: Sorry, a _single-quote_ was missing in ´textDate`.